# Map CapsLock key to Return

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I want to remap my <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key to work as if it was a <kbd>Return</kbd> key. I've created a xmodmap file like this:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Return
```

If i run it from Terminal:

```
xmodmap /home/me/mods/remove_caps
```

It works fine - when I press <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> it works as if I pressed <kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> state does not change. But when I add a command to startup like this:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 20;/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/kuba/mods/caps"
```

The <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key DOES work as return, but it also changes <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> state. The only difference that I can see is that once the xmodmap command is executed 20s after startup, it misses the `remove Lock = Caps_Lock` line. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04, adding

```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 1 && /usr/bin/xmodmap /home/kuba/Settings/xmodmap"
```

To Autostart Entries does the job